# InputEvent to make text Bold instead of document.execCommand('bold',false,null)

Tags: javascript, input, dom-events, contenteditable

I've been trying to find an example of how to use InputEvent with format bold on text to make it bold instead of

```js
document.execCommand('bold',false,null);
```

This is related to [InputEvents](https://w3c.github.io/input-events/). I wanted to switch to InputEvents in a `contenteditable` text editor instead of using `document.execCommand` to manipulate the content.